# OpenGL Detect clicking on object inside another object

Tags: c++, opengl

I am pretty new to openGL programming and I encountered a problem I just need some advice on. Basically I have a button which has a simple function to just print something out on the console when it is clicked and that works fine on its own. However I also have a rectangle which I use as mini window or a container to hold buttons.

The problem I have is when the button is on top of the rectangle, the clicking functions for that button isn't detected, instead the clicking functions for the rectangle which is printing a message on the console saying the rectangle was clicked, is detected. On the other hand, if I drag the rectangle away and just leave the button on its own on the window, the clicking functions will work for the button.

Is there any advice you guys can give me or tell me what to research to aid me with detecting the button click while my button is inside  of the rectangle? by the way I am not using Glut on my project.

Answer (score 2):

A good start would be, if you told us, how you're actually getting the user input and how you're processing it. Whatever you do, it got nothing to do with OpenGL though, because **OpenGL doesn't deal with user input** and **OpenGL doesn't deal with scene management.**

OpenGL *draws* things. One point, line or triangle at a time. After it pushed some pixels to the framebuffer canvas it forgets about what it just did. There's no scene in OpenGL. There are no models in OpenGL. So whatever you do, it's using something else.